# null id generated for composite PK

Tags: spring, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-roo

I have the following tables [image] and the following relationship table too: [image], which  has a composite PK as follow:

UserRole.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooJpaEntity(identifierType = UserRolePK.class, versionField = "", table = "UserRole", schema = "dbo")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
@RooToString(excludeFields = { "idApplication", "idRole", "idUserName" })
public class UserRole {
}
```

UserRole_Roo_DbManaged.aj

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdApplication", referencedColumnName = "IdApplication", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Application UserRole.idApplication;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdRole", referencedColumnName = "IdRole", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Role UserRole.idRole;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdUserName", referencedColumnName = "IdUserName", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Users UserRole.idUserName;
```

But also exist a PK table:

```
@RooIdentifier(dbManaged = true)
public final class UserRolePK {}
```

And its identifier class (UserRolePK_Roo_Identifier.aj)

```
privileged aspect UserRolePK_Roo_Identifier {

    declare @type: UserRolePK: @Embeddable;

    @Column(name = "IdRole", nullable = false)
    private Long UserRolePK.idRole;

    @Column(name = "IdUserName", nullable = false, length = 16)
    private String UserRolePK.idUserName;

    @Column(name = "IdApplication", nullable = false)
    private Long UserRolePK.idApplication;
```

The way how I'm setting the service objec to save is:

```
UserRole userRole= new UserRole();
userRole.setIdApplication(app);
userRole.setIdRole(invited);
userRole.setIdUserName(user);
appService.saveURole(userRole);
```

***app*** has been set and saved before (same transaction), as well as ***invited*** and ***user*** objects.
Since user (from Users table with composite PK: IdUserName which is a String  ), is defined as follow, otherwise doesnt work.

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooJpaEntity(versionField = "", table = "Users", schema = "dbo")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
@RooToString(excludeFields = { "quotations", "taxes", "userRoles", "idCompany", "idPreferredLanguage" })
public class Users {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "IdUserName", length = 16, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private String idUserName;
}
```

So, the error that I'm getting is:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.domain.UserRole; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.domain.UserRole
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class UserRole {
   @PrePersist
   private void prePersiste() {
       if (getId() == null) {
           UserRolePK pk = new UserRolePK();
           pk.setIdApplication(getIdApplication());
           pk.setIdRole(getIdRole);
           pk.setIdUserName(getIdUserName());
           setId(pk);
       }
   }
}
```

Roo is generating the fields on `UserRole` entity and its `id` embedded class, but is not the same thing (UserRole.idRole is not the same than UserRole.id.idRole). In your example, you fill the `UserRole` fields, but not the `id` fields. This code makes it for you before entity is persisted.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @jmvivo, I did but I got this: <code>UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
 Unsaved transient entity: ([com.domain.Users#anco])
 Dependent entities: ([[com.domain.UserRole#com.domain.UserRolePK@1ec5735a]])
 Non-nullable association(s): ([com.domain.UserRole.idUserName])</code>

Comment: thank you, I fix the issue, what I did is to add .saveAndFlush() instead of simple .save(Entity) for app, invited and User objects, so UserRole could use the IDs created before.

Answer (score 2):

In my case if the follow example tries to be persisted in DB, then similar Exception mentioned above is thrown:

```
EntityExample e = new EntityExample();
repositoryExample.save(e);
//throw ex
```

This is caused due to missing id field values which needs to be set something like that:

```
EntityExample e = new EntityExample();
e.setId(new EmbeddedIdExample(1, 2, 3));
repositoryExample.save(e);
```